# Wrong Interop.Shell32.dll being loaded suddenly

Tags: c#

I have a program that has been working just fine, however when I made a small change to the way the program loads from its ini, the zipping function stops working. I stepped through the program and found the error to be occuring on the following line:

```
    var fs = File.Create(zipPath);
    fs.Write(emptyZip, 0, emptyZip.Length);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
    var sc = new Shell32.ShellClass();
    var srcFlder = sc.NameSpace(program.Path); //THIS LINE
    var destFlder = sc.NameSpace(zipPath);
    var items = srcFlder.Items();
    destFlder.CopyHere(items, 20);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    ZippedPrograms.Add(zipPath);
```

I double checked the variables `program.Path` and others being sent to the `ShellClass()`, and they are not null or empty. This is the actual error that pops up when the program gets to this line:

[image]

Doing some googling I find that apparently the `Shell32.dll` I have referenced in my program does not work right with 7 (or server 2008, the target environment), and I needed  to reference the XP version instead (52kb versus 48kb dll size). One of the links where I found this info: [click me](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/835800d1-7bd0-4bed-baa0-88212226c16b).

So I created a virtual machine and installed WinXP Professional on it, and navigated to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\` and copied the `Shell32.dll` located there to my host computer. Strange enough, the DLL is ~8mb in size rather than the 52kb I was expecting. When I add it as a resource from VS2012, I browse to the copied file and add it (with copy local), but then for some reason it ends up being 48kb in size and the program continues to crash at the above mentioned line.

I have tried using DotNetZip along with other C# libraries for zip management, and for some reason they never work properly (creating corrupted ZIP files, not creating them at all, refusing to add random files/folders to the archive, etc). Before this issue the program was working flawlessly, so more than anything I am confused as to why all of a sudden it is not working and why the `Shell32.dll` is not A) the 8mb version I reference, and B) 'stripped down' to 48kb. On top of that, I checked the current deployment of the program, which lacks some features of the current version, among other things, and the DLL there is the 48kb size, and this particular deployment has worked with no problems.

I should also mention that I am currently running Windows 8 Pro, and developing in VS2012. The deployment environment is Windows Server 2008 R2. I originally wrote this program in VS2010 on Windows 8 Ultimate. When I opened the project for the first time in VS2012, there was **no** upgrade dialogue. All OS's listed (except WinXP Pro) are x64.

Has anyone had any experience with these issues/happenings? Any insight/tips/solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Dragging across an outdated system dll to a newer version of Windows is something that's just bound to fail, especially if it's (as in this case), a COM interop DLL. If Windows 8 is running a COM service, it's going to be running it with its "own" version of the DLL. If you then try to interact with it using an interface DLL for a different version, you'll get an interface mismatch. As you've seen, `E_NOINTERFACE`.

You're trying to use a version 6 DLL to communicate with a version 8 service. It's bound to run into problems.

The difference in size *might* have something to do with Visual Studio stripping the deployment DLL down to just the interfaces, instead of including all the implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I am just confused why it stopped working all of a sudden after it was functioning fine for a while.

Comment: So you had it working in Windows 8 with no locally copied DLL? But then stopped working after you made a change to how the program reads from an ini. But instead of reversing that change made to the ini loading, you brought across a different DLL version? If that's the case, my suspicion would be that it wasn't working as fine as you initially thought.

Comment: Sort of, I don't think I tested it on win8 (as I just upgraded to it). It was working without any hitches on win7 (original development OS) and win server 2008 R2 (deployment environment), but as soon as I attempted to update the app (added some features and ini capabilities), everything went down the tubes. Note that I did not change anything to the zipping logic, nor did I attempt to get a new DLL. Also, it was copied local.